# Script (effect) to show a sphere full of logos (or maybe they are stars, read)

Tags: javascript, html

I remember that I've seen this effect long time ago on a website.

It was a page full of logos (so I imagine is a famous website) where I think every logo represent a star.
You can move a bit the logos (and click on them) to view everything cleverly.

I can't remember the website but maybe someone used/found it. If someone can point to a library that does an effect like this or has a link to previous mentioned website I will be graceful.

I usually create scripts by myself but I think I need quite a lot of maths here and is my weak point :\

Maybe it was a **sphere** (transparent) full of logos, not the universe full of stars (you can't really understand it, but hopefully I can give you the idea).

Thanks for any answer.

**Edit 1:**
I think this is the idea I have: http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/09/3d-sphere-using-jquery/
maybe it's a "tag cloud" (but with logos) what am I looking for?
I don't know the name.

**Edit 2:**
I think this is exactly the effect I'm looking for: http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php
However this uses canvas. While I like new technologies I need ie8 support so it would be nice to have a similar effect without using the canvas element

Comment: I don't get why this question is not constructive. Is very detailed, I already opened a question like this and was appreciated. Here I'm looking for a particular javascript effect and a library to apply it and lucky I found it by myself. What's the problem if someone else will find it useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the script I've found have backup scripts up to ie7, so definitely I've found it and it's working gracefully.

Thanks anyway and sorry for the autoanswer.

http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php